# how to map my distributed shell script to ansible

Tags: bash, ansible, sudo

I'm new to Ansible, and I'm trying to "rewrite" my distributed shell scripts to Ansible. Generally I have exchanged ssh keys from one of my servers to a bunch of others (user1 user). And this user has sudo right (to perform "sudo bash") on all of these clients. I need to run some commands as a second user (user2) on all of those hosts. So my script looks like:

```
hosts="hosts.txt"

while read line;
do
    ssh user1@${line} bash << EOF
    sudo bash << EOT
    su - user2 << EOS
    /path/to/command arg1 arg2
EOS
EOT
EOF
done < ${hosts}
```

Is there some ansible way to do this?

I found that there is a way to become/become_user, but this is related to sudo, and user2 doesn't have any sudo rights.

Is the solution to grant user1 sudo rights to be able to execute /path/to/command like user2? Is there any other way to avoid adding new sudo rights?

Comment: Strange way of writing `ssh user1@${line} sudo su - user2 "\"/path/to/command arg1 arg2\""`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as a proof of concept, put the hosts in your `hosts.txt` in your [ansible inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html) and try it with the following playbook:

```
---
- hosts:
    - all
  remote_user: user1

  tasks:
  - name: your task
    shell: '/path/to/command arg1 arg2'
    become: True
    become_user: user2
    register: output

  - name: DEBUG
    debug:
      var: output
```

Execution should be done with `ansible-playbook your_playbook.yml`.

If your `/etc/sudoers` is somewhat ugly and this doesn't work, than you can replace the task `your task` with the following:

```
  - name: your task
    shell: 'sudo bash -c "su - user2 -c \"/path/to/command arg1 arg2\""'
    register: output
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not split lines containing **su**, and **command**, and prefer something like:

```
su - user2 -c '/path/to/command arg1 arg2'
```

If **user2** needs its GNU/Bash environment, you can change your line to:

```
bash -c "su - user2 -c '/path/to/command arg1 arg2'"
```